# ~0 = -1 and ~1 = -2 in C program

Tags: c

I have an array of type uint8_t storing 0's and 1's. When I do the negation on each element I get an array of -1's and -2's. How is this possible? How do I make it perform the way it's supposed to?

Comment: *"How do I make it perform the way it's supposed to?"* It *is* performing the way it's supposed to. So the question is, "Why did you expect it to do something else, and what exactly did you expect it to do?"

Comment: How are you printing them?

Comment: He seems to be asking how he's getting negative numbers from an unsigned integer (not about 2's complement). The answer is that he's printing the value incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually doing the right thing, but it's just being displayed improperly. Negative numbers are represented using two's complement. To convert a number to negative, you do: `NOT(positive) + 1`.

As an example, to convert 2 to a negative number:

1. `+2          = 00000010`
2. `not(+2)     = 11111101`
3. `not(+2) + 1 = 11111110`

This means that `-2` is represented by `11111110` in binary. Notice how this is actually the bit inverse of `+1`, which is `00000001`. This explains why you're seeing what you are, but why isn't it showing you the positive like expected? This depends on how you're displaying it. You most likely used `printf` or a similar string formatter with `%i` rather than `%u`, so the compiler is casting it automatically for you. If you change your format, it should be fixed.

If you're just wanting to change between `true` and `false`, use `!` instead of `~`.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now. I'm trying to implement a function to negate the binary representation of a signed integer. So instead of using ~ I'm just using if condition on each element, after all that then add 1 to the result. However when I do that I get 255 in the 32nd position. I'm really confused since it's suppose to be 1.

Comment: Actually I think I might have figured out. Let me try it.

Comment: @user90593: "... negate the binary representation of a signed integer" but in your question you have the type uint8_t.  Signed or unsigned?

Comment: @user90593 Also, if you're wanting to negate the binary representation, using `~` is the right thing to do. Perhaps if you update your question to give a more detailed sample input and your expected output, we can help you more.

Comment: The 255 number was just a result of a mistake on my part - I forgot to change ~ to ! like you suggest in one line of the code.

Comment: "so the compiler is casting it automatically for you" --> no casting occurs here

Comment: @MattMcNabb Does casting not occur when you interpret a `unsigned int` as a `signed int`? I just assumed it was similar to a `reinterpret_cast`, since it doesn't require any CPU cycles, but the compiler sees it as a different type.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, the `~` operator flips all the bits. For a signed char integer, the above is correct. For example, for a signed char, 0=00000000, 1=00000001, -1=11111111, -2=11111110.

If you want values for "true" and "false", usually false is all-bit-zero (=0) and "true" is all-bits-1 (=-1). Then, ~true==false and ~false==true.

If you want to toggle between 0 and 1, you can use the xor operator `^` to toggle specific bits; in this case, you want to toggle the lowest bit, so use `^1`. 0^1==1 and 1^1==0.